# How do I get the background-position-y in firefox using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox

```
$(elem).css('backgroundPositionY')
```

does it on chrome, ie, and safari, but not Firefox (nor Opera I believe).  You'd think jQuery would have a polyfill but it doesn't, as of 1.5.  How can I easily get the background Y position for e.g. background animations (for e.g. parallax)?

**EDIT**: [Tell Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=550426) you want `background-position-[x,y]` support. (use the "vote" feature, not comment, unless you have something prescient to add). Bug has been open since 2010 tho (3 years now) so don't hold your breath for a fix. :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
var backgroundPos = $(elem).css('backgroundPosition').split(" ");
//now contains an array like ["0%", "50px"]

var xPos = backgroundPos[0],
    yPos = backgroundPos[1];
```

Comment: I've read that this is how you're supposed to post if you figure something out on your own and want to share, I hope this is kosher!  Please delete if I'm incorrect here.

Comment: Beat me to it, wow.  I had to do a little experimenting to make sure it would work properly.

Comment: OK it's been a couple weeks and no better answer's come in.  Tho it feels kinda dirty, I'm going to go ahead and accept my own answer.

Answer (score 7):

Here is my hacky solution:

```
var $jQueryObject = jQuery('#jQueryObject');
var backgroundPosition = $jQueryObject.css('background-position');
// backgroundPosition = "0% 0%" for example
var displacement = backgroundPosition.split(' '); // ["0%", "0%"]
var y = Number(displacement[1].replace(/[^0-9-]/g, ''));

// As suggested, you could also get the float:
var yFloat = parseFloat(displacement[1].replace(/[^0-9-]/g, ''));
```

Here `y` would be a number that would either be the percent or pixel offset depending on your situation.  I did a little regex to get rid of the non-number characters so you can get the number as a javascript Number.

Comment: I beat you because I cheated. :p I knew the answer before I posted the question.  Have a well earned vote!  Might I recommend parseFloat() to extract the number from the string?  It's a bit tidier than the regex.

Comment: since Number is not always desirable as: var x = Number(1); is not exactly the same as var x = 1; could instead do var y = +(displacement[1].replace(/[^0-9/g,''));

Comment: .replace(/[^0-9-]/g, '') will convert 23.34534% to 2334534. I am sure that this is not expected behaviour. Add "." to your expresion. .replace(/[^0-9-.,]/g, '') now 23.34534% will give you 23.34534

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, some browsers (such as Chrome) report `css('background-position')` or `css('backgroundPosition')` as `left <x> top <y>`, while others (Internet Explorer, Firefox, Opera) report it as `<x> <y>`.  The following worked for me:

```
var x, y, pos = $(elem).css('background-position').split(' ');

if(pos[0] === 'left') {
  x = pos[1];
  y = pos[3];
} else {
  x = pos[0];
  y = pos[1];     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off sequoia mcdowell's answer you can also do

```
var yPos = $(elem).css('backgroundPositionY');
```