# Using jQuery to change the background position of a sprite in CSS for all elements

Tags: jquery, css, background, sprite, background-position

I have an image sprite that is the background of the main div, with a dozen links inside it. Instead of writing the values of the background-position in the CSS file for each link when it's hovered, I want to do it in jQuery so that the background-position y increases by 550px (the x position will remain the same).

The Markup:

```
<div class="compass">
    <a class="facebook" href="#">&nbsp;</a>
    <a class="twitter" href="#">&nbsp;</a>
    <a class="youtube" href="#">&nbsp;</a>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.compass {
    background-image: url('../images/compass.png');
    background-position: top;
    height: 550px;
    position: relative;
    width: 567px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.compass a{
    background-image: url('../images/compass.png');
    background-position: top;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
a.facebook {
    height: 51px;
    width: 26px;
    left: 151px;
    top: 190px;
}
```

So the idea is to write a CSS rule style for each link indicating the x and y positions of the background image. Then, on hover, the y position would increase by 550px. On mouseout, it would go back to hot it was (a 550px decrease).

I've started the jQuery syntax but can't figure it out:

```
var originalPosition = obj.css('background-position');
$(".compass a").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).css('backgroundPosition', originalPosition + 550 + "px")
    },
    function(){
        $(this).css('backgroundPosition', "");
    }
)
```

Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edited to work in FF as well.

```
$(".compass a").hover(function() {
    var bgpos = $(this).css('backgroundPosition').split(' ');
    $(this).css('backgroundPosition', bgpos[0] + ' ' + (parseInt(bgpos[1],10)+550) + 'px');
}, function() {
    var bgpos = $(this).css('backgroundPosition').split(' ');
    $(this).css('backgroundPosition', bgpos[0] + ' ' + (parseInt(bgpos[1],10)-550) + 'px');
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/3TxW9/2/)

Credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6821820/1331430) for the FF hack.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. I'm trying it out but it's not working...hmmm

Comment: @TarekShalaby It works in Chrome but not FF, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/3TxW9/). I'll try to put together a hack for FF.

Comment: @TarekShalaby Updated answer, check if it's of use now. `=]`

Comment: I used this recently and discovered that IE8 only supports 'background-position-x' and 'background-position-y', not 'background-position'. Whereas firefox supports the opposite (other browsers are more forgiving and appear to support either syntax).

In the end my solution was to avoid using background-position for the technique entirely and instead used the same idea but with a child div, and animated the movement by updating the 'left' property.

You'll need position: absolute; on the child div, and overflow:hidden on the container. Avoid background-position!

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off creating the hover and standard background positions as separate CSS rules, and using `addClass` and `removeClass`.

```
$(".compass a").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).addClass('hoverIn');
    },
    function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hoverIn');
    }
);
```

css:

```
.compass a.hoverIn {
    background-position: 550px;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be the same as using the hover CSS pseudo selector? `.compass a:hover` instead of a new class and no jQuery required.

Comment: The problem is that the end result is not 550px, it's (current y position) + 550px. That's why the value's always going to be dynamic depending on the original y position of the background image for that particular link.

Answer (score 1):

Check this one out, freshly made for you. Does the job.
http://jsfiddle.net/Anr24/

Alternatively, wouldn't it be nicer to just define the :hover attributes in CSS?

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! It's not working, though, not even within the jsfiddle.net code you put together. CSS hover wouldn't work because the value's dynamic; I want to increase the height by 550px, so the end result depends on the original value of the y position of the background image.

Comment: Code? Explanation of code? Answers? This is missing all of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an arbitary amount to the background position value, try using +=X and -=X where X is the value to add / remove.

I might have the finer details wrong but something like this:

```
$(".compass a").hover(
    function(){
    $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '+=50px')
},
function(){
    $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '-=50px');
}
)
```

...should do the trick

Here's a quick fiddle to show you what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/erinfreeman/Jj46m/